# Multiple text file output in R

Tags: r, csv, text, text-files

I am trying to convert csv cells to text files in R (using RStudio). The first column is the ID, and the second column is the text I want to output into separate text files.

This code:

```
work_dir = "C:/Users/MyName/Documents/MyFolder"
setwd(work_dir)

data = read.csv("MyData.csv")


sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
dataID <- gsub(" ", ".", data[i, 1])
fileName <- paste0("C:/Users/MyName/Documents/MyFolder/", dataID, ".txt")
writeLines(c(paste("#", data[i, 1]), data[i, 2]),
           con = fileName)})
```

is giving me the following error:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/MyName/Documents/MyFolder/60000  3.txt': 
Invalid argument
```

The name of the file should be "600003.txt" (ID number of first piece of data in csv).

Comment: what is `dataID`? Did you mean `essayID`?

Comment: I do not know exactly how your data looks like but it is possible that there is either leading or trailing whitespace. Can you try this when reading data: `data = read.csv("MyData.csv", strip.white=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I'm going to revise it now

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out [temporarily]:

There was some kind of formatting issue with the `("#", data[i, 1])` part of the writeLines command.

When I removed it, everything worked fine and outputted each cell as its own text file.